# creating john [:watched] TheMatrix and john [:watched] matrix [:at] AMC

Tags: neo4j

can we create relationship like below 
john [:watched] TheMatrix and john [:watched] TheMatrix [:at] AMCCinema
mary [:watched] TheMarix and john [:watched] TheMatrix [:at] NewCinema

Can we create relations like above with out duplicating "TheMatrix" node?

Answer (score 0):

You can either put the Cinema as "where" property on the `:watched` relationship.

Or if that constellation is really important in your domain, you can also create an intermediate `:Viewing` node, that can be connected to John, Mary and The Matrix.